# Background-Image does not show properly on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, background-image

I want to show background-image on body. I have a css file and I controlled body properties with it. I want to set background-size:100% but it doesn't work on IE7 or IE8.  It works on Chrome,Firefox and IE9. How can I change it for IE7 and IE8 ?

My CSS file:

```
body
     {

         background-image:url('http://www.blablabla.com/images/arka3.png');
         background-size: 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-attachment: fixed;
         background-position: left;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS for the body tag.

```
body
     {
        background: url('http://www.blahblahblah.com/images/arka3.png') #EBEBEB repeat-x 0 0;
 }
```

You can also cut your background image to be 1 or 2 px wide to save on load time.

You can also just add the new CSS in a conditional CSS statement to only apply in IE7 and 8.

NOTE: I didn't have time to QA all browsers but I did check IE 8 and FF.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks for attention :) Can you change the image url please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="bgImg" src="img.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bgImg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

​Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/7EMQb/1/)